# Which have happened "last night"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does this sentence mean that we went to the restaurant last night, or that Jane recommended us the restaurant last night? This is a translating practice in my textbook, and this is the answer is provided on the last page of the book. But I cannot understand why I should write this answer. Because I cannot understand what the sentence really means if I didn't see the question first. Since I didn't have a good ability of English, there's no reason that I distrust the textbook. But at the same time, I really don't know how to interpret this kind of sentence rightly.

> We went to the restaurant Jane recommended **last night**.

Answer (score 7):

That is ambiguous.

Now pragmatically I'd assume you went to the restaurant last night.  I guess this because 1) people usually go to restaurants in the evening. and 2) if she'd recommended it last night, there isn't much time for you to have gone since then.

But adding context, or changing a word can change the interpretation

> Last night, before we left, I asked Jane about where we should get breakfast when we arrive in Paris. She told me about this great little restaurant that serves coffee and croissants and is close to the station. We went to the restaurant Jane recommended last night.

> We went to the breakfast bar Jane recommended last night.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question~

Answer (score 0):

I would say that (contrary to first impression) this is *not* ambiguous.  "Last night" is next to "recommended" (and "we went" is not)... so "last night" qualifies "recommended".  That is... last night, Jane recommended the restaurant.  [Note that, technically, "we" might have gone three weeks ago to this restaurant that Jane has just recommended.]

Conversely, to say that {we went last night}, one would insert a comma, to separate "last night" from "restaurant" (and thus imply that it qualifies something else, with the only candidate being "we went").

Similarly, when *speaking* the version with a comma, one would use a pause to indicate the comma.  ("We went to the restaurant Jane recommended... last night.")  ...Or better still, one would plan ahead, and say "Last night, we went to the restaurant Jane recommended."

[Conversely to the above, one might say "We went to the restaurant Jane recommended last night."... meaning (i.e. intending to mean) that we went last night.  In this case, I would allow that it is "ambiguous" [scare quotes (i.e. *not* technically ambiguous)]... where "ambiguous" means that the audience is left to work out, from the real-world context, that actually there should have been a comma.]